# Remove Group array element field from Jolt

Tags: arrays, json, mapping, transformation, jolt

I have this group array element in my jolt spec called "data",
but I want it removed from my spec.

```json
[
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "integrationEntities": {
          "integrationEntity": [
            {
              "integrationEntityHeader": {
                "integrationTrackingNumber": "gut.govan@my.com_666886_20230525163038"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: What's your expected output, is this `[ { } ]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you should adjust the match `"data":""` within a **remove** transformation spec at the level where `data` array stays such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "data": ""
      }
    }
  }
]
```